# Docker multi-stage build and mounting/sharing from previous stage

Tags: maven, docker

I would like to use multi-stage builds to avoid downloading all the Maven dependencies required by my Java project every time I build the app.

I am thinking of resolving the Maven dependencies in a first stage, then building the app in a second stage which would require access to the dependencies downloaded in the previous stage.

If I understood well multi-stage builds I could copy files created in the first stage to the second stage, but ideally I would like to be able to "mount" or "share" the folder from the first stage where the dependencies live instead of copying the files, is it possible? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

EDIT:
This was the first stage I was thinking about

```
FROM some-image-with-maven AS maven-repo
WORKDIR /workspace/
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -B -f pom.xml dependency:resolve
```

But since the pom file will be different most of the times (because I would like to share this stage across projects), the following step that resolves dependencies will download all of them again (instead of using a cached layer).

Comment: From what I learned from [here](https://medium.com/travis-on-docker/multi-stage-docker-builds-for-creating-tiny-go-images-e0e1867efe5a), you can name each stage using the keyword `AS` and referencing that build stage

Comment: Yes but I have only seen examples executing COPY using the stage name

Answer (score 1):

Answering from *the future*...

If using `buildkit` or compatible (most people probably are by now), you can mount a previous stage with a [`bind` mount](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypebind).  Something like this would accomplish what the original post was asking:

```
FROM someimage as build
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/.m2_repository -B -f pom.xml dependency:resolve

FROM runtimeimage
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src/ ./src/
RUN --mount=type=bind,from=build,source=/.m2_repository,target=/.m2_repository \
    mvn package
```

But more to the point, there is also a [`cache` mount](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypecache) that you can use instead and you would incur the cost of downloading all the deps on first run, but subsequent would be able to find those deps in the cache:

```
FROM runtimeimage
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src/ ./src/
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/.m2_repository,sharing=locked \
    mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only copy stuff from the first stage if you are not using volumes. When using volumes, you can share data between stages which are basically separate container instances.
Since missing to clean up volumes is often not handled properly I suggest to keep to the copy strategy. There is no real benefit using bind-mount to share data over the copy approach.

Comment: You can't use volumes at build time, they are only available at runtime as of 17.06. There are discussions to add support to mount directories, but that's still in the discussion/design phase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this currently. To share from one build stage to the next, the only option is to `COPY` files from one stage's directory to the current stage.

To use the first stage as a build cache and avoid copying all the dependencies, I'd run your build in that first stage. Or you can make a second intermediate stage that is `FROM stage1name` if you want additional separation between the stages. The output of your build can then be copied to the final layer, avoiding the need to copy all the build dependencies.

Comment: My goal is to use the first stage as a Maven repo for multiple projects that I build differently (since the stage will be cached if I am not wrong). My first stage currently ends with `RUN mvn -B -f pom.xml dependency:resolve` then I build in the next stage (specifically for each project), but I need to copy 1GB of dependencies before building, which I ideally would like to avoid.

Comment: Each line of a Dockerfile becomes a layer that is cached, it's finer grain than the entire stage. You can either append to that first stage some additional build commands, or you can create an intermediate build stage that is `FROM stage1name` to achieve your goals.

Comment: When I say "build" I meant `mvn package ...`. Let's say I build project A and project B differently because I want to run tests or not, output stuff or not, etc. so my Maven build command can not be reused, this is why it would happen in a second stage specific to the project, the first stage would be the same for all my Dockerfiles though, so dependencies wouldn't have to be downloaded again at each Maven build.

Comment: The cache happens at a lower level than that. Two different Dockerfile's for different applications, creating different images, but with the same first few lines, will reuse the layers of the other image's build cache when you build it. Docker looks at the previous layer and the command you are running, if they match, it skips to use the resulting layer from the cache. If there's still confusion, please update your question with an MCVE.

Comment: Actually I realized that it can not work the way I was imagining it: I resolve the dependencies after copying the `pom.xml`, so since the pom file is different most of the times, all dependencies are downloaded again at every Docker image build...